# Why is this query faster without index?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, query-performance

I inherited a new system and I am trying to make some improvements on the data. I am trying to improve this table and can't seem to make sense of my findings.

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calls](
    [CallID] [varchar](8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [RecvdDate] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [yr] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Mnth] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CallStatus] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Category] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [QCall] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [KOUNT] [int] NOT NULL)
```

This table has about 220k records in it. I need to return all records that have a date greater than specific date. In this case 12/1/2009. This query will return about 66k records and it takes about 4 seconds to run. From past systems I have worked on this seems high. Especially given how few records are in the table. So I would like to bring that time down.

So I'm wondering what would be some good ways to bring that down? I tried adding a date column to the table and converting the string date to an actual date column. Then I added an index on that date column but the time stayed the same. Given that there aren't that many records I can see how a table scan could be fast but I would think that an index could bring that time down.

I have also considered just querying off the month and year columns. But I haven't tried it yet. And would like to keep it off the date column if possible. But if not I can change it.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the query I am trying to run and test the speed of the table. I usually put out the columns but just for simplicity I used * :

```
SELECT *
FROM _FirstSlaLevel_Tickets_New
WHERE TicketRecvdDateTime >= '12/01/2009'
```

EDIT 2: So I mentioned that I had tried to create a table with a date column that contained the recvddate data but as a date rather than a varchar. That is what TicketRecvdDateTime column is in the query above. The original query I am running against this table is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Calls
WHERE CAST(RecvdDate AS DATE) >= '12/01/2009'
```

Comment: What is the *exact* query you're running please?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. Let me edit and add. I forgot to include.

Comment: What is TicketRecvdDateTime? Is that a computed column somewhere; or why is that not in your table declaration?

Comment: Sorry that query was from a new table I tried to create with a column of date rather than varchar for the date field. Let me fix query for original use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be encountering what is referred to as the Tipping Point in SQL Server. Even though you have the appropriate index on the column, SQL Server may decided to do a table scan anyway if the expected number of rows returned exceeds some threshold (the 'tipping point').

In your example, this seems likely since your is turning 1/4 of the number of rows in the database. The following is a good article that explains this: `http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx`

Comment: This very well could be because I have noticed with an index or without I get the same speed on the query. I was thinking that maybe it is just at a point in the number of records in the table that a table scan could perform just as fast as an index scan. But wanted to see if others had better ideas.

Comment: You should check the other answers.  While this may be true, folks are missing the point that the index is on a varchar, not an actual date..... Look at Remus Rusanu below,  and practice flipping on Actual Execution Plan to see her/his point.

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT *` will usually give a poor performance.

Either the index will be ignored or you'll end up with a key/bookmark lookup into the clustered index. No matter: both can run badly.

For example, if you had this query, and the index on TicketRecvdDateTime [INCLUDEd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) CallStatus, then it would most likely run as expected. This would be [covering](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/)

```
SELECT CallStatus
FROM _FirstSlaLevel_Tickets_New
WHERE TicketRecvdDateTime >= '12/01/2009'
```

This is in addition to Randy Minder's answer: a key/bookmark lookup may be cheap enough for a handful of rows but not for a large chunk of the table data.

Comment: I agree that * is not a good choice. I only included that for simplicity in the post. But the query I run I list out all the columns in the query. Since there was no difference between * or all columns for this query I just posted the easier one.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is faster w/o an index (or, more precisly, is the same speed w/ or w/o the indeX) because and index on `RecvdDate` will *always* be ignored in an expression like `CAST(RecvdDate AS DATE) >= '12/01/2009'`. This is a non-SARG-able expression, as it requires the column to be transformed trough a function. In order for this index *event to be considered*, you have to express your filter criteria *exactly* on the column being indexed, not on an expression based on it. This would be the first step.

There are more steps:

- Get rid of the VARCHAR(10) column for dates and replace it with the appropriate DATE or DATETIME column. Storing date and/or time as strings is riddled with problems. Not only for indexing, but also for correctness.
- A table that is frequently scanned on a range based on a column (as most such call log tables are) should be clustered by that column.
- It is highly unlikely you really need the `yr` and `mnth` columns. If you really do need them, then you probably need them as computed columns.

.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calls](
    [CallID] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [RecvdDate] [datetime](10) NOT NULL,
    [CallStatus] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Category] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [QCall] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [KOUNT] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Calls_CallId] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([CallID]));

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cdxCalls ON Calls(RecvDate);

SELECT *
FROM Calls
WHERE RecvDate >= '12/01/2009';
```

Of course, the proper structure of the table and indexes should be the result of careful analysis, considering *all* factors involved, including update performance, other queries etc. I recommend you start by going through all the topics included in [Designing Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190804.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Can you alter your query?  If few columns are needed, you can alter the SELECT clause to return fewer columns.  And, then you can create a covering index that includes all columns referenced, including `TicketRecvdDateTime`.

You might create the index on `TicketRecvdDateTime`, but you may not avoid the tipping point that @Randy Minder discusses.  However, a scan on the smaller index (smaller than table scan) would return fewer pages.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming RecvdDate is the TicketRecvdDateTime  you are talking about:

SQL Server only compares dates in single quotes if the field type is DATE. Your query is probably comparing them as VARCHAR. try adding a row with '99/99/0001' and see if it shows at the bottom.

If so, your query results are incorrect. Change type to DATE.

Note that VARCHAR does not index well , DATETIME does.

Check the query plan to see if its using indices. If the DB is small compared to available RAM, it may simply table scan and hold everything in memory.

EDIT: On seeing your CAST/DATETIME edit, let me point out that parsing a date from a VARCHAR is a very expensive operation. You are doing this 220k times. This will kill performance.

Also you are no longer checking on an indexed field. a compare with an expression involving an index field does not use the index.